# 0xC0000005 Error on Multi Thread Animation

Tags: c++, multithreading, animation, console-application, borland-c++

So I was making an application using C++ Console, with multi threading as below, then I got an  error 0x0000005.

The first time it run it was working as usual. Can anyone help me with this problem?

I am using Code::Blocks IDE with Borland C++ 5.5, and I am planning to make this into Borland C++ 5.02

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

void linesmov(int mseconds, int y);

void linesmov(int mseconds, int y)
{
    int i=0;
    while (true)
    {
        i=i+1;
        // Or system("cls"); If you may...
        gotoxy(i,y);   
        cout << "____||____||____"; 
        gotoxy(i-1,y);
        cout << " ";
        Sleep(mseconds);
        if (i>115)
        {     
            i=0;  
            for(int o = 0; o < 100; o++)
            {
                gotoxy(0,y);   
                cout << "                  ";
            }
        }
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI mythread1(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    printf("Thread inside %d \n", GetCurrentThreadId());
    linesmov(5,10);
    return 0;
}
DWORD WINAPI mythread2(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    printf("Thread inside %d \n", GetCurrentThreadId());
    linesmov(30,15);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HANDLE myhandle1;
    DWORD mythreadid1;
    HANDLE myhandle2;
    DWORD mythreadid2;
    myhandle1 = CreateThread(0,0,mythread1,0,0,&mythreadid1);
    myhandle2 = CreateThread(0,0,mythread2,0,0,&mythreadid2);
    printf("Thread after %d \n", mythreadid1);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce an error in MCVS15 using `void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
 COORD c = { x, y };
 SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), c);
}` instead of borland specific `gotoxy`. May be  `gotoxy`  is the root of problem?

Comment: Are you sure that `gotoxy` is thread-safe?

Comment: Did your debugger tell you something?

Comment: you're not wating for threads to finish

Comment: There's almost no way this is thread safe. You've got 2 different threads calling `gotoxy` to set the output location of text in the console - there's a classic race condition here.

Comment: It's using borland C++ 5.5 Compiler. It wont be able to be reproduced via MCVS15. gotoxy is not the root of the problem. I can use it in an infinite loop, so I am sure it's not the problem. @SmitYcyken

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't know. How to make sure that gotoxy is thread safe?

Comment: @Sean What do you mean by that?

Comment: @SazeimSaheem - One thread can call `gotoxy` but before it does its ouput another thread may also call `gotoxy`, so the location of your output will be garbage.

Comment: @SazeimSaheem, just for the experiment, try to replace Borland `gotoxy` to that function I posted before. It only uses WINAPI.

Comment: @SmitYcyken Ok. I just checked on your function, it was to me brilliant, but.. The error still occur... :/

Comment: @SmitYcyken Thank you for your function. After I did some experiments, like changing std::cout to printf(); and changing Sleep(); to sleep(); and using your function, I've been able to Eliminate the crash.

The problem seems to be at std::cout, while using printf(); didn't cause the program to crash.
Using the ordinary gotoxy will cause some funny bug in the program lol -> [Image](https://imgur.com/gallery/c2wC2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these solutions in comments including mine are definitely not the way how it should be done. The main problem is lack of synchronization between threads and lack of processing their termination. Also, every function should be checked for thread-safe compatibility or should be wrapped to match it.

Considering `std::cout` since c++11 we have some data race guarantees:

> Concurrent access to a synchronized (§27.5.3.4) standard iostream
>   object’s formatted and unformatted input (§27.7.2.1) and output
>   (§27.7.3.1) functions or a standard C stream by multiple threads shall
>   not result in a data race (§1.10). [ Note: Users must still
>   synchronize concurrent use of these objects and streams by multiple
>   threads if they wish to avoid interleaved characters. — end note ]

So lask of synchronization primitives is oblivious according to this note.

Considering processing of thread termination.

```
HANDLE threadH = CreateThread(...);
...
TerminateThread(threadH, 0); // Terminates a thread.
WaitForSingleObject(threadH, INFINITE); // Waits until the specified object is in the signaled state or the time-out interval elapses.
CloseHandle(threadH); // Closes an open object handle.
```

[TerminateThread()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx), but be aware of this solution, [because ..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737417/kill-a-running-thread)

[WaitForSingleObject()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx)

And this is only first steps to thread-safe way.

I would like to recommend C++ Concurrency in Action: Practical Multithreading by  Anthony Williams for further reading.

#### Rude solution for synchronized output

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex _mtx; // global mutex

bool online = true; // or condition_variable

void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    COORD c = { x, y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), c);
}

void linesmov(int mseconds, int y) {
    int i = 0;
    while (online) {
        i = i + 1;
        // Or system("cls"); If you may...

        _mtx.lock(); // <- sync here
        gotoxy(i, y);
        std::cout << "____||____||____"; gotoxy(i - 1, y);
        std::cout << " ";
        _mtx.unlock();  

        Sleep(mseconds);
        if (i > 75)
        {
            i = 0;
            for (int o = 0; o < 60; o++)
            {
                _mtx.lock(); // <- sync here
                gotoxy(0, y);
                std::cout << "                  ";
                _mtx.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI mythread1(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    std::cout << "Thread 1" << GetCurrentThreadId() << std::endl;
    linesmov(5, 10);
    return 0;
}
DWORD WINAPI mythread2(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    std::cout << "Thread 2" << GetCurrentThreadId() << std::endl;
    linesmov(30, 15);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    DWORD mythreadid1;
    DWORD mythreadid2;
    HANDLE myhandle1 = CreateThread(0, 0, mythread1, 0, 0, &mythreadid1);
    HANDLE myhandle2 = CreateThread(0, 0, mythread2, 0, 0, &mythreadid2);

    std::cout << "Base thread: " << GetCurrentThreadId() << std::endl;

    getchar();

    online = false;

    WaitForSingleObject(myhandle1, INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(myhandle2, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(myhandle1);
    CloseHandle(myhandle2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: May I ask what is #include <mutex> @Smit Ycyken

Comment: [synchronization primitives - mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/mutexes),  [std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)

Comment: At least this fixed the problem, but it's C++11, so I can't make it useable on older compilers... (T_T )

Comment: WINAPI [critical section object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx) provides synchronization similar to that provided by a mutex object

Comment: Try to wrap it to the class and get rid of global variables, and it is better to use WINAPI `CreateEvent` to create an [event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732015/will-using-createevent-to-create-open-an-even-that-already-exists-reset-the-sign) instead of `bool online`

Comment: Also, it does not hurt to use the return value of WINAPI functions to check runtime errors and handle them.

Comment: After I checked again, the point why I used multi threading is I want so make the animation move at a different speed.

After I saw a few times, I found out that the animation was going on the same speed, then skipping to the actual place it supposed to be. Any ways to fix this?

One hell of a problem I think (-_- ')

Answer (score 0):

a) Both gotoxy not outputting via std::cout are not thread safe /synchronized. You need process-wide mutex to synchronize that

b) exception is likely due to fact that you do not use `WaitForMultipleObjects` in main to wait for threads to finish. Depending on hardware and optimization main may exit before threads finish their work.

Comment: Output to `cout` is safe.

Comment: The problem was at using std::cout. Replacing it with printf has prevented the crash, but left with some buggy result with gotoxy, but the cause of the crash was std::cout. Anyways thanks!

Comment: @molbdnilo Output to cout is NOT safe.

Comment: @SazeimSaheem Yes it is, but if your program is undefined, changing anything at all may make a crash go away.

Comment: @molbdnilo  c++11 explicitly says that is possible to syncronize output but it is not so by default, yet without additional syncronization (see Smit's answer) you will still get garbage output. Before c++11 (and that's OPs case) there was no guarantee for that to be safe